How to run logic the first time a route is accessed in Express.js?
I'm using Express.js, and I want to initialize a cache on every initial request to a route, and on the subsequent ones use the cached value.
For now, I do something like this:
let hasRun = false;

app.get('/my-route', async (req, res) => {
  if (!hasRun) {
    await redisClient.set('key', {});
    hasRun = true;
  }

  const data = await redisClient.get('key');
  res.send(data );
});

But if I have multiple routes, it becomes kind of messy.
What do you suggest?
Note: Even though in my example I use Redis, I'm looking for a general approach, not necessarily with Redis. (And in any case, using .get here will not help, because it will always return a value)

have a map of routes? {route1: false, route2:false}

Did you mean multiple routes when you said multiple requests?

Instead of tracking whether or not the route has been accessed, why not test whether or not Redis returns a value for that key?  If it doesn't, write the value.

@David I thought of it, but I want to refresh the cached values every time my server goes up

@Ba2sik: Then add that operation as part of the server's initial startup?

i'd go with David's approach. you could flush the cache in your main index file

@David That's a good idea. My thought was to initialize on route access to avoid unnecessary initialization for rarely used routes.
